# How to get all the values of multiple fields with the same name in a search document in the Google App Engine search api?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

For fields with a unique name, you can just do `doc.field('prop').value`, but when you try to do that with a field with a name that occurs multiple times, you get

```
ValueError: Must have exactly one field with name prop, but found 3.
```

I've looked through the source of the Document class, but I couldn't find a method that returns a list of values associated with fields of a given name. Is there a good way to do that?

To be clear, I'm trying to do this with a Document, not a ScoredDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking through the source code, I ignored any methods that started with underscores, because most of them were either private, or methods like `__eq__`. I clearly shouldn't have done that, because the document class implements `__get__`, so if a document has multiple fields named 'prop', you can do the following to get all its values:

```
values = [field.value for field in doc['prop']]
```